# Input with font-size of 0 when combined with input-prepend/append

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to use bootstrap in a Rails application and I already tried to include the bootstrap CSS directly or using bootstrap-sass/anjlab-boostrap-rails.

In the three of them, I am facing a strange issue that I did not uderstand.

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="input-append">
  <input type="text" /><a href="#" class="btn">?</a>
</div>
```

The rendering is ok but when I typewrite something in the field, nothing appears. Investigating further, I found that the input-prepend/append set the font-size to 0 and then the text seems to disepear.

Did I forget something when I written my HTML code ? Is it correct ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code works for me, can you post a link or reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed this issue as well and was able to track down the cause.

Bootstrap's (version 2) css rules for `.input-append` and `.input-prepend` set the font size to 0 to eliminate horizontal whitespace. Several elements are then reset to the correct font size but `.btn` is not included in the reset. By adding `.btn` to the list of elements getting the restored font size I was able to fix the issue.

**Note:** This is no longer an issue in Bootstrap 3 since the new `.input-group` styles rely on floats rather than the previous inline-block approach (with the whitespace hack).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue. I did not realize that I had one other stylesheet in conflicts with this part of my code. The code implied in the conflict is the following one:

```
input, textarea {
  font-size: 1.1em !important;
}
```

When I comment this style declaration, it works again like a charm. I did not understand exactly why this is causing some strange behavior I had. In my case, this definition came after the inclusion of bootstrap.css.